# Use Shopify product category field in Algolia

Tags: shopify, algolia

There is any way to add the *product category* field to Algolia attributes? In the Shopify app, I see that the integration by default adds the *product type* and *vendor* fields, for example, but not the product category.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Product category is not part of the product schema that is indexed to Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/shopify/sending-and-managing-data/schemas/?client=ruby#product-variant-schema

You could add this data on your metafields and then index the metafields to Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/shopify/sending-and-managing-data/metafields/?client=ruby#index-metafields

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).